# Blank selected text in VBA Word is coming up as 2 characters

Tags: vba, find, selection, paragraph

When I run the my VBA code on the following text, it works fine till it gets to the paragraph break.  I try to run a test for paragraph breaks but it comes up as FALSE:

*OK, so that now we're recording.
Uhm, so I spoke with Berry,*

*which actually your own berries
team now, right?*

The output looks like this:

*OK, so that now we're recording. Uhm, so I spoke with Berry,  which actually your own berries team now, right*

Here is my original code:

```
Sub OneLine()
    Dim charCount As Integer
    
    'Go to End of document and add "
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" """
    
    'Go to beginning of Document
    Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst
    
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    'Count how many characters are in Selection
    charCount = Len(Selection)
    Set myRange = Selection
    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="""", Forward:=True
    'MsgBox (myRange.Find.found)
    
        Do While myRange.Find.found = False
                   
            If charCount > 1 Then
                Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
                Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
    
                Selection.TypeBackspace
                Selection.TypeText Text:=" "

                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
                charCount = Len(Selection)
                
            Else
                Selection.Delete
                
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
                charCount = Len(Selection)
                
            End If
            Set myRange = Selection
            myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="""", Forward:=True
            'MsgBox (myRange.Find.found)
       Loop
       
       Selection.TypeBackspace
       Selection.TypeBackspace
       Selection.TypeBackspace
        
    Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst
    
End Sub
```

I tried using `Find.Text:= "^p"` statement with an IF THEN but it came out as FALSE.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I've also tried the following separately:
^b
^l
^n

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

i used the following lines:

```
With Selection.Find
     .Execute FindText:=vbCrLf
     .Forward = True
End With
```

Originally I was only looking for one thing, paragraph break or line break but not the combo of line feed and carriage return: `vbCRLf`.  I was also using `"vbCrLf"` which is wrong because at that point it's looking for that string.

This is my final code:

```
Sub OneLine()
    Dim charCount As Integer
    
    'Go to End of document and add "
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" """
    
    'Go to beginning of Document
    Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst
    
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    'Count how many characters are in Selection
    charCount = Len(Selection)
    Set myRange = Selection
    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=""""
    'MsgBox (myRange.Find.found)
    
        Do While myRange.Find.found = False
                   
            If charCount > 1 Then
                
                With Selection.Find
                    .Execute FindText:=vbCrLf
                    .Forward = True
                End With
            
                If ((Selection.Find.found = True) And (charCount = 2)) Then
                    
                    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
                    Selection.TypeBackspace

                    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
                    charCount = Len(Selection)
                    
                Else
                    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
                    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
    
                    Selection.TypeBackspace
                    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "

                    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
                    charCount = Len(Selection)
                End If
            Else
                Selection.Delete
                
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
                charCount = Len(Selection)
                
            End If
            Set myRange = Selection
            myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=""""
            'MsgBox (myRange.Find.found)
       Loop
       
       Selection.TypeBackspace
       Selection.TypeBackspace
       Selection.TypeBackspace
        
    Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst
    
End Sub
```